# Skip to Previous and Next song notification in MPMusicplayercontroller?

Tags: ios, notifications, audio-player, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitemcollection

I am working on music player app where I am using

```
MPMusicPlayerController iPodPlayer
```

to play the songs. I want to receive

```
skip to Next and Previous song notifications
```

to my app when I am in forground when user skips from ipod music controller. I couldn't find any solution, is there  anyway to acheive this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have another reason to want to know when a song is skipped, (trying to do a certain action based on user skipping a song, for instance from steering wheel controls)  So I'd be curious to see the answer to the original question vs a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using single media to play the song, I changed it to MPMediaCollection to play the songs in queue and which handles playing next and previous songs.